# Como Convertir JS a JSON con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tengo un archivo ext .JS remoto que me trae esta data, entiendo que con un preg_mach_all lo puedo resolver pero quisiera saber si hay algun modo mas tecnico. Gracias

```
var alf="https://globaltvplus.club:25463/live/DarkPlayOficial/Duraremos145236987ads/41.m3u8";
var anime="http://tv.latintvweb.com:25461/live/OmarCruz/foev3rRNU2/2864.m3u8";
var bleach="http://flowfhd.xyz:25461/live/playtoo/sdlpefeflrmdowp26f1r564f3/72622.m3u8";
var bobsponja="http://xtream.encohd.co:25461/live/JXCH2323DC/D3LG6g7Z9E/72.m3u8";
var cantinflas="http://flowfhd.xyz:25461/live/playtoo/sdlpefeflrmdowp26f1r564f3/38473.m3u8";
var chespirito="http://tv.latintvweb.com:25461/live/OmarCruz/foev3rRNU2/4654.m3u8";
var corajeelperrocobarde="https://globaltvplus.club:25463/live/DarkPlayOficial/Duraremos145236987ads/73.m3u8";
```

Comment: Puedes ser más especifico en  lo que quieres?

Comment: ¿Qué quieres resolver? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que quieres realizar, pues esas son solo `URLS` que quieres hacer con ellas?, cual es el formato de salida esperado?

Comment: Tan solo es convertir en un Array esta data o en formato JSON